# How to find a DLL from a using statement in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, namespaces, using

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

I have been given source code of a project which uses a bunch of third-party DLLs. How can I find out which `using` statement is using which DLL?

For example I have this statement:

```
using Mnp;
```

How can I find out that which DLL has the `Mnp` namespace?

I put cursor on `Mnp` and right-click to open right-click menu. There I tried 2 options:

- Go to Definition F12
- Go to Implementation  Ctrl+F12

But in both cases I get the same error message:

> Cannot navigate to the symbol under the caret.

I was hoping Visual Studio can point me the DLL in `References` section which has the namespace `Mnp`.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Object Browser.  In the search text box put in the string of the Namespace you want to find.  On the left side panel, choose the correct namespace returned.  On the lower right side panel, it will say Member of  (being your assembly name).

Answer (score 1):

You can create types in the same namespace in multiple libraries and in your current application.

However if your program currently compiles, you can:

- remove the `using Mnp;` line from the source code
- attepmt to build the solution, which will fail because it cannot find one or more *types*
- re-include the `using Mnp;` line
- use `Go ot Definition` on one of these types to find out where it came from

If it doesn't compile *because* you are missing a dll, you can open the `.csproj` file in a text editor to see which dll's it was using.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I usually right click and choose "Find All References" option.